# NHibernate.Search - Set Index Directory at runtime

Tags: lucene.net, multi-tenant, nhibernate.search

I am building a Multi-Tenant application and would like to create seperate Indexes for each tenant, however I can't seem to find a way to set my index directory at runtime for NHibernate.Search when indexing my data.

```
fullTextSession.Index(entityInstance);
```

This seems to be using the index directory from my config file, is there a way around this?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, though in my case each tenant has its own sessionfactory, so after reading the common configuration, just before building the session factory, I am overriding the settings for NHibernate.Search.

Comment: yeah i figured this out in the end and this is exactly what I ended up doing too.